# How to register HostFunction into WASM Runtime?

Tags: runtime, wasm, wasmtime

When I read the code of the [wasmtime executor](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/client/executor/wasmtime), I can't understand the way to register the HostFunction to the wasm module. What is the role of the [`sp_wasm_interface::HostFunctionRegistry`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/client/executor/wasmtime/src/imports.rs#L95) trait? How is the parameter `func` of the function [`register_static`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/client/executor/wasmtime/src/imports.rs#L107) passed in?

I have to solve this problem when I want to use a different wasm runtime instead of wasmtime or wasmi. However, I can't find a way to get the HostFunction's function body.